# How to draw only some lines in MATLAB's pcolor plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization

I have a block matrix that I visualize with `pcolor`. I'd like to somehow visualize the block structure, so I'm looking for a mixture between `shading flat` inside each block and `shading faceted` at the borders, something like

```
a | b c | d e f
- + - - + - - -
g | h i | j k l
m | n o | p q r
```

(where each letter represents a color value and the lines separate the blocks)
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `imagesc` or `imshow` (using `axis xy` or `axis ij` as required for orientation). Then simply set the `xtick` and `ytick` locations to those required by your lines, and call `grid on`.

So for example

```
imagesc(im);
grid;
set(gca, 'xtick', [1.5, 2.5, 5.5],...
         'ytick', [3.5, 4.5],...
         'gridlinestyle', '-');
```

**Note**: to change image drawing such that you can work with integer gridline locations, you could instead call `imagesc(0.5 : (size(im,1)-0.5), 0.5 : (size(im,2)-0.5), im)` as this offsets the pixel locations by -0.5. 
Also while you can change the axis `linewidth` property, I don't think you can get access to the grid line widths directly - for that level of control you might want to write a quick little function to add lines which would give you complete control over every line; or modify this [this script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28244-gridxy2) which does just that!

Comment: Thank you, and silly me! There I was deliberately inserting NaNs into my matrices when there is `grid on`...